# Can I achieve effect of nested aggregation functions without another query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, window-functions

I have columns `a`, `b`, `c` in a table `table1`. I need a query like the following:

```
select func1(a), func2(b,func1(a)) from table1 group by c.
```

I am currently storing the result of `func1(a)` in a CTE using window functions and then performing the above group by. The execution plan shows 2 aggregations happening - one for window aggregation and another for hash aggregation for the second group by. It should logically be possible to do it with a single aggregation in a single pass.

I am using Postgres9.3. I tried nesting window functions and nesting aggregation functions but I get the error that both are not possible in Postgres.

I would basically like for the above aggregations to be done in a single pass.

Comment: Please add your version of Postgres and the query you are currently using. It's unclear where window functions come into play here? Add the table definition for `table1` and, ideally, a small test case, possibly as [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter The [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/28167/1) has been added. As you can see in its execution plan, two scans are happening, one on the original table and another on the CTE

Comment: A fiddle is always welcome. However, it displays a different type of query than the one in your question. Window functions have to be treated differently from plain functions. Please clarify.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I am using the window function to add `func1` as another column to the original table. I don't need to use window functions but came up with that as the only way to get the answer for now. If I could use `sum(a*b)/sum(a)` which is `func1`, in `func2` which is `sum(a*func1)`, that would be perfect since that should need only a single pass over the data without the need for creation of CTE. So something like `select sum(a*(sum(a*b)/sum(a))) from original_table group by c` would be ideal

Comment: @erwinbrandstetter Unfortunately the actual formula in func2 is pretty complicated and the formula I gave for func2 was just a substitute for it and cannot be simplified

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you use a subquery or CTE (like you already mentioned) to avoid repeated evaluation of a function:

```
SELECT c, a1, func2(b,a1) AS ba1
FROM  (SELECT c, func1(a) AS a1, b FROM table1) sub
GROUP  BY c;
```

#### Example in the SQL Fiddle

Are you aware that the expression can be simplified to `sum(a * b)` when excluding **rounding errors** stemming from division of integer numbers?

This:

```
with temp_view as (
   select (sum(a * b) over (partition by c) / sum(a) over (partition by c)) as func1_out, a, c
   from   test_table1
   )
select sum(a * func1_out) AS f2
from   temp_view
group  by c;
```

is the same as (except for rounding errors):

```
SELECT sum(a * b) AS f2
FROM   test_table1
GROUP  BY c;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/87835/3) demonstrating the (non-)difference.

Comment: The problem I am facing is not that func1 is getting computed again but that in order to compute func2, a second pass over the CTE is needed